# How can I see the Parameters of Reports on Reportserver?

Tags: reporting-services

I read that all Reports from SSRS are stored as RDL (Report definition) on the Reportserver database.

**Question: How can I see all create parameters for a report in this database? I want to find Reports with particual parameters.**

I check already the Reportserver database but I did not find any table with a particul report and the used parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters are listed in the `Parameter` column of the `Catalog` table (`ReportServer.dbo.Catalog`)

The parameters are stored as XML so you cannot read them directly.

The following code will return reports with their parameter names, the parameter's label and its datatype.

```
SELECT 
        Cat.ItemID, cat.[Path], cat.Name
        , p.* 
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog cat
        JOIN (
                SELECT ReportID = ItemID 
                                ,ParameterName = params.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
                                ,Prompt = params.value('(Prompt/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') 
                                ,DataType = params.value('(Type/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
                FROM (
                                SELECT C.ItemID, C.Name,CONVERT(XML,C.Parameter) AS ParameterXML
                                FROM  ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C
                                WHERE  C.Content is not null
                                AND  C.Type  = 2
                                ) a
                cross apply ParameterXML.nodes('//Parameters/Parameter') q (params)
        ) p 
            on cat.ItemID = p.ReportID
```